# Configuring .htaccess to display php errors on subdomain only

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a domain on a shared web server (using CPanel) for which I have just created a subdomain as a test environment for development work before it goes live on the main domain.

I want to turn on php error reporting for this subdomain only, which I believe is best done in the .htaccess file as I don't have access to the php.ini file on a shared server.

When I add the following to .htaccess in the root directory of the subdomian I get an 500 internal server error on the subdomain.

```
php_flag display_start_up_errors ON
```

```
php_flag display_errors ON
```

```
php_value error_reporting -1
```

```
php_flag html_errors ON
```

Even if just one of these 4 lines is there I get the 500 error.

As far as I can see my code is correct for turning on errors, so I am guessing I need further rules, either here, or somewhere else?

I am fairly new to this, so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Some providers do not allow PHP settings to be changed with .htaccess. You should be able to turn on enough error reporting in your code using `ini_set('display_errors','1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors','1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your code.

Comment: Can you inspect the server's error log? It should tell you why that error was thrown

Comment: Dave, thanks for that info. If that is the case, I will do it that way. Just a pain to have to do it in each php file.

Comment: Nico, the error in the log I am seeing is this: Invalid command 'php_flag', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration